# Benchmarking a page or its controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have recently inherited some AngularJS code (I cannot post the code), and noticed a huge delay on the initial load. It is completely unacceptable, and I need to optimize it. Using Chrome's timeline, I noticed there is a lot of scripting which isnt particularly meaningful.

[image]

I tried using Batarang, but even the longest expression was just a date function and was negligible compared to everything else. I have a feeling its the controller since its incredibly fat and spaghetti, and I need someway to benchmark this controller or at least figure out what is the bottleneck before I start refactoring.

Comment: Take a look here to remove the debug information from the executed code. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just making a promise and subtracting the difference in unix time to get an idea of how long it took. There are other tools such as benchmarkjs, but this is all I needed to figure out where the problem was.

```
var oldTime = (new Date).getTime();
deferred = $q.defer()
deferred.promise.then(function() {
   # Code in here
}).then(function() {
   console.log("Time taken: ", ((new Date).getTime() - oldTime))
})
deferred.resolve();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the open source Chrome plugin Angular-performance, you can benchmark specific controllers in Angular applications: https://github.com/Linkurious/angular-performance